# Coded UI is identifying the control but not performing any action

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have written the below code,

```
       WinWindow w = new WinWindow();
       w.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Card Action";
        w.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "#32770";
        w.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Window";

        WinWindow w2 = new WinWindow(w);
        w2.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
        w2.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.VisibleOnly);
        w2.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlType]="Window";
        w2.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Insert Card";
        w2.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId] = "2032";

        WinButton b1 = new WinButton(w2);
        b1.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
        b1.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.VisibleOnly);

        b1.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Button";
        b1.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Button";
        b1.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "Insert Card";
        b1.DrawHighlight();
        Mouse.Click(b1);
```

It has identified the control but unable to perform click action.

Error:
Test method CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception:
Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked control visible and retry the action. Additional Details: TechnologyName: 'MSAA' Name: 'Insert Card' ClassName: 'Button' ControlType: 'Window'

Output Screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhbgj.png

Please help me to sort out this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hallo Reshma and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please tell us what you already did to find the source of this problem.
The error is telling you another control is in front of the button. Please check the application code, perhaps some transparent control is in front of it?

Comment: This is a common problem when developing Coded UI tests. There are many web pages discussing the problem and its possible solutions. What have your web searches found and why did that not help you?

Comment: @AdrianHHH, I have searched many websites regarding this error. All I came know is hierarchy and search properties should be proper for element to be identified. For this i have also used DrawHighlight() to check whether the element is identified properly or not. And yes it has identified correctly but is not getting clicked.

Comment: @PixelPlex,Thank you :)                                                                          
 There is no other control visible to us as I have opened only one window as shared in the screenshot

Comment: Are those 3 controls visible on your screenshot (main window, combobox and button) the only ones used on your test? Do you get the same error when recording the test instead of hand writing it? If the recorded test succeeds where your code does not, you should check the recorded code and compare it with your code.

Comment: @PixelPlex, thanks for the reply. As I am working on this error,  I have commented all the other methods to make sure that no other control is blocking.And I see the same error in the recorded script also.  Error: Test method CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception:
Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked control visible and retry the action. Additional Details: TechnologyName: 'MSAA' Name: 'Insert Card' ControlType: 'Button'.

Comment: Commenting out other methods in the Coded UI tests will not prevent other blocking controls. They are likely to be from the application being tested. Try running the Coded UI test in debug mode. Run it to the point of failure, then cancel/abandon that test leaving the application running. Next, use the assertion builder part of the Coded UI record and generate tool to explore the area of the screen that has the wanted, but blocked, control. I expect you will find that something is placed over the wanted control.